# Dominance-directed (tournament) graph metrics

Tags: r, social-networking, graph-theory, igraph

I am interested in deriving dominance metrics (as in a dominance hierarchy) for nodes in a dominance directed graph, aka a tournament graph. I can use R and the package igraph to easily construct such graphs, e.g.

```
library(igraph)
```

create a data frame of edges

```
the.froms <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)

the.tos <- c(2,3,4,3,4,4)

the.set <- data.frame(the.froms, the.tos)

set.graph <- graph.data.frame(the.set)

plot(set.graph)
```

This plotted graph shows that node 1 influences nodes 2, 3, and 4 (is dominant to them), that 2 is dominant to 3 and 4, and that 3 is dominant to 4.

However, I see no easy way to actually calculate a dominance hierarchy as in the page: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~daddel/linear_algebra_appl/Applications/GraphTheory/GraphTheory_9_17/node11.html .  **So, my first and main question is does anyone know how to derive a dominance hierarchy/node-based dominance metric for a graph like this using some hopefully already coded solution in R?**

Moreover, in my real case, I actually have a sparse matrix that is missing some interactions, e.g.

```
incomplete.set <- the.set[-2, ]

incomplete.graph <- graph.data.frame(incomplete.set)

plot(incomplete.graph)
```

In this plotted graph, there is no connection between species 1 and 3, however making some assumptions about transitivity, the dominance hierarchy is the same as above.

This is a much more complicated problem, but if anyone has any input about how I might go about deriving node-based metrics of dominance for sparse matrices like this, please let me know. I am hoping for an already coded solution in R, but I'm certainly MORE than willing to code it myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For non-graph theorists, it might be better to explain the dominance concept within your question. It's up to you though; someone else may know what you're talking about. Also, if your question is about the math and not the coding, SO might not be the right place for it.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I modified it to be clearer, I hope. In short, my first question is definitely about programming, while the second is perhaps more about the math...though I was hoping to bypass the math for now and find a coded solution to fiddle with while I try and understand the math of the more complicated aspect of it.

Comment: Would the `relations` package be of any use? It seems to be able to deal with calculations for dominance of one node over another - http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relations/vignettes/relations.pdf

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what exactly is your question. What would be the output for your example graph? You want to derive a metric, but what would this metric measure at all? Why is this is a stackoverflow question if you don't know what you want to calculate?

Comment: @GaborCsardi Thanks a lot for the response! I do know what I want to calculate. I want a number describing the rank in a dominance hierarchy of every node in a directed graph, like shown in the link I provided in the original post. Thus, in the example code I provided, node 1 would be 1, node 2 would be 2, node 3 would be 3 and node 4 would be 4. I would imagine in more complicated networks it is possible to have values of this metric that are ties, or ranges, or something like that, particularly if the network is not a directed acyclic graph or if it is a sparse matrix.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks! I am looking at that now. I don't see where it can calculate dominance though, but I'm probably missing something. The part near the end of the vignette about linear orders seems like it's on the right track, maybe I need to think harder about how to co-opt it.

Comment: @forlooper - I think I have it figured out - try my answer below and see if it works for a more complex dataset.

Comment: @forlooper: OK, but then this is just the out-degree of the nodes, isn't it? I mean, if the ranking is based on the number of nodes dominated by a particular node. Your link does not really explain what a "dominance hierarchy" is, actually it does not even contain the word "hierarchy".

Comment: @GaborCsardi. Thanks! I'm embarrassed to say I hadn't considered that possibility. In the complete case above it does return the correct answer. In the incomplete second example, however, it doesn't work. Either way, I appreciate the pointer towards this measure, it will be very helpful later. A dominance hierarchy is a ranking among units, e.g. vertices, summarizing which units are dominant to which others. There may of course be ties, but generally (simplest case) there is a transitive relationship such that one can make some assumptions about nodes for which no data is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is perfect or that I fully understand this, but it seems to work as it should from some trial and error:

```
library(relations)
result <- relation_consensus(endorelation(graph=the.set),method="Borda")
relation_class_ids(result)
#1 2 3 4 
#1 2 3 4
```

There are lots of potential options for `method=` for dealing with ties etc - see `?relation_consensus` for more information. Using `method="SD/L"` which is a linear order might be the most appropriate for your data, though it can suggest multiple possible solutions due to conflicts in more complex examples. For the current simple data this is not the case though - try:

```
result <- relation_consensus(endorelation(graph=the.set),method="SD/L",
                             control=list(n="all"))
result
#An ensemble of 1 relation of size 4 x 4.

lapply(result,relation_class_ids)
#[[1]]
#1 2 3 4 
#1 2 3 4
```

Methods of dealing with this are again provided in the examples in `?relation_consensus`.

Comment: This works very well. In particular, the second option here seems to return the correct linear order even if the matrix is missing a value, as in the second example I provided. I appreciate it a lot, thanks @thelatemail. As an aside, in your code above you called an object "the.new". I'm not sure where this came from, though it doesn't affect this answer being right. Cheers

Comment: @forlooper - no worries, "the.new" error is fixed now too - that was just the name of my working dataset.