# How to sort a data.table based on a set of inequality constraints?

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I have a set of "x < y" inequality constraints and I would like to sort the rows of a data.table based on these.

For example,

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0)
ineqs <- unique(data.table(
  X = sample(letters, 10, replace = T),
  Rel = "<",
  Y = sample(letters, 10, replace = T)
))
ineqs
    X Rel Y
 1: x   < b
 2: g   < f
 3: j   < e
 4: o   < r
 5: x   < j
 6: f   < u
 7: x   < m
 8: y   < s
 9: r   < z
10: q   < j
```

So, if I start with a table of sorted letters,

```
dt <- data.table(Foo = letters)
    Foo
 1:   a
 2:   b
 3:   c
---    
24:   x
25:   y
26:   z
```

How can I adjust the row order to satisfy my constraints? Also, I am certain that my constraints are *valid* (i.e. none of the constraints contradict each other).

Comment: Not clear, you mean `ineqs[order(X, Y)]`?

Comment: @ANG no. I'm interested in sorting the rows of `dt`, not `ineqs`.  However, I want the rows of `dt` to satisfy the constraints. For example, the row with "x" should come before the row with "b".

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970380/dominance-directed-tournament-graph-metrics/18971361

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(igraph)
g = ineqs[, graph_from_edgelist(cbind(X,Y), directed=TRUE)]
o = names(topo_sort(g))

dt[, v := factor(Foo, levels = o, ordered=TRUE)]
dt[order(v)]


    Foo    v
 1:   x    x
 2:   g    g
 3:   o    o
 4:   y    y
 5:   q    q
 6:   b    b
 7:   m    m
 8:   f    f
 9:   r    r
10:   s    s
11:   j    j
12:   u    u
13:   z    z
14:   e    e
15:   a <NA>
16:   c <NA>
17:   d <NA>
18:   h <NA>
19:   i <NA>
20:   k <NA>
21:   l <NA>
22:   n <NA>
23:   p <NA>
24:   t <NA>
25:   v <NA>
26:   w <NA>
    Foo    v
```

All of the terms that aren't in `ineqs` are sorted to the end.

If the graph of your relation has cycles, you should get a warning in `topo_sort`. This tells you your task is not well defined for some terms in `ineqs`.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm curious: As the order is not necessarily unique, how does this select one particular order? Is it random?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yeah, I was curious, too. The docs just say "Every DAG has at least one topological sort, and may have many. This function returns a possible topological sort among them."

Comment: Very neat, I like this a lot! I have to admit that I'm not very familiar with graph theory, but it seems that [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) has a running time linear in the number of vertices and edges (which is obviously *much* faster than my exhaustive "create-all-permutations" approach). The Wiki article also lists different algorithms and discusses (briefly) how other solutions can be created.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Cool, thanks for the info. I just figured "this looks like a directed graph" and searched the igraph docs for sorting functions (http://igraph.org/r/doc), but didn't know more about it.

Comment: Aha! I knew this was a graph theory problem, but totally forgot [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) was a thing.  Thanks Frank!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I misunderstood but this is not a trivial sort, and there doesn't necessarily exist one unique order.

Let me give you an example. Consider the conditions

```
    X Rel Y
1: x   < b
2: g   < f
```

Various orders are conceivable

```
        x < g < f < b
g     < x     <     b   <   f
g     < x     < f < b
g < f < x         < b
        x < g <     b     < f
        x <         b < g < f
```

all of which satisfy the conditions laid out in the first two lines.

---

I was interested in seeing how an exhaustive & crude implementation would do, where we pre-calculate all possible permutations and then eliminate those that do not fulfil the pairwise conditions.

To illustrate, we will use 4 letters only and the first two lines of the pairwise condition data.

Here are my results:

1. To start, we define the four letters and calculate all permutations using `gtools::permutations`.

   ```
   char <- c("b", "f", "g", "x")

   library(gtools)
   perm <- as.data.frame(permutations(length(char), length(char), char))
   ```

   There are 24 possible permutations.
2. We now read in the pairwise condition data

   ```
   df <- read.table(text =
       "X Rel Y
   x   < b
   g   < f", header = T)

   # Convert factors to character vectors
   df[] <- sapply(df, as.character)
   ```
3. We now loop throw the permutations and the pairwise conditions and flag those rows in the permutation data that do not satisfy any of the pairwise conditions.

   ```
   rmv <- c()
   for (i in 1:nrow(perm)) {
       # Here we loop throw all possible permutations and eliminate those that
       # do not fulfil the pairwise conditions
       for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
           # Here we loop throw the pairwise conditions
           cond <- eval(parse(text = sprintf("`%s`", df[j, "Rel"])))(
               which(perm[i, ] == df[j, "X"]),
               which(perm[i, ] == df[j, "Y"]))
           if (cond == FALSE) {
               rmv <- c(rmv, i)
               break
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. The remaining permutations that satisfy the conditions are then

   ```
   perm[-rmv, ]
   #   V1 V2 V3 V4
   #16  g  f  x  b
   #17  g  x  b  f
   #18  g  x  f  b
   #20  x  b  g  f
   #23  x  g  b  f
   #24  x  g  f  b
   ```

Comment: I agree that there can be *multiple* sorts that satisfy my constraints but I'm not sure how to achieve any of them.  Can you come up with a mechanism to achieve one valid sorting?

Comment: @Ben As I said, that's not a trivial problem. An exhaustive & crude way would be to pre-compute all orderings (for letters `a-z`) and then eliminate those that do not fulfil the conditions. You're then left with those orderings that satisfy your pairwise conditions. I don't know how realistic that will be for your real data as the number of orderings will increase very quickly with the number of letters.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Sorting given pairwise orderings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287306/sorting-given-pairwise-orderings)

Comment: @Ben I've played around with an exhaustive & crude approach for 4 letters and the first two lines to demonstrate a potential starting point. Please take a look.

Comment: Nicely done.  I appreciate the effort, but my real data is too large for this technique to work.

Comment: @Ben Yup, this is definitely not a feasible solution for larger datasets;-) I like the graph theoretical approach a lot, it's just important to keep in mind that this will return only one of the potentially many possible orderings. Thanks for an interesting question!